# Merging two databases in Android

Tags: java, android, database, import, restore

In my app I have implemented options to backup and restore the database to a SDcard. When I restore the database, I must have the currently saved data included with the backed up data. How to make this possible?

This is how I am restoring database.

Restore:

```
 try {
            File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File data  = Environment.getDataDirectory();

            if (sd.canWrite()) {
                String  currentDBPath= "//data//" + "PackageName"
                        + "//databases//" + "DatabaseName";
                String backupDBPath  = "/BackupFolder/DatabaseName";
                File  backupDB= new File(data, currentDBPath);
                File currentDB  = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                FileChannel dest = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), backupDB.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to attach backed to your current db in this way:

```
sqlite> ATTACH DATABASE 'testDB1.db' as 'DB1';
sqlite> ATTACH DATABASE 'testDB2.db' as 'DB2';
sqlite> ATTACH DATABASE 'testDB3.db' as 'DB3';
```

[SQLite - ATTACH Database](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_attach_database.htm)